# Why is correlation written with 2 r?

Tags: orthography

Hey english stackexchange!
I was wondering why correlation is written with 2 r's?
I'd expect the word to come from relation with the prefix co-, thus making it "corelation". However, the German word "Korrelation" is also written with 2 Rs. I expect there to be a background story to this.
Maybe someone can shed some light into this :-)

Comment: You may type `correlation etymology` into Google.

Comment: Note that the same phenomenon occurs with _correspond_ but not with _corecipient_, _coresearcher_, _coresident_, or _coruler_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underlying prefix is Latin *con-*, not *co-*. In Latin, this prefix became *cor-* before words that began with R.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: sources: https://www.google.com/search?q=correlation+etymology (above normal results) & https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cor-#Prefix @RichardKayser

Comment: co-, cor-, as well as con-, & col- are all just **forms of** ***com-***, usually meaning "with, together".  Selection depends on the following letter.  E.g. before `-n-` → `con-`, e.g.: `con'nection`.  Source: https://www.etymonline.com/word/com-  (See also https://www.etymonline.com/word/co- and https://www.etymonline.com/word/con-.)